# Java SocketChannel : Why wrap-flip-write doesn't work but wrap-write does?

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer, socketchannel

Assume we have a Java `SocketChannel` connected to a server which is waiting for incoming data:

```java
SocketChannel server = SocketChannel.open();
server.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port));
```

And we send our request as below:

```java
byte[] request = "This is a request for server!".getBytes();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(request);
buffer.flip();
int write = 0;
while (buffer.hasRemaining())
    write += server.write(buffer);
System.out.println(write);
```

The above code returns `0` which means **it doesn't write any bytes to the channel !**

But if I remove the `buffer.flip()` line, it will work fine and data is sent:

```java
byte[] request = "This is a request for server!".getBytes();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(request);
int write = 0;
while (buffer.hasRemaining())
    write += server.write(buffer);
System.out.println(write);
```

**Why is this ?!**

Comment: When you wrap it assumes you are ready to read from the start.  When you flip(), you are ready to write up to where you read, which is nothing.  flip() is also for changing to reading what you just wrote.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The last sentence isn't correct. flip() doesn't undo itself. See the Javadoc. The old limit is lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the issue myself, so I'm writing it here on `StackOverflow` to share the info and be useful for anyone else facing the same problem.

According to the [java-doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap%28byte%5B%5D%29) for `ByteBuffer.wrap()`:

> The new buffer's capacity and limit will be `array.length`, its position will be zero, and its mark will be undefined.

And the [java-doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip%28%29) for `Buffer.flip()` says:

> Flips this buffer. The limit is set to the current position and then the position is set to zero. If the mark is defined then it is discarded.

The answer is now clear: `wrap()` sets the buffer's position to zero, and `flip()` sets the buffer's limit to the current position (which is zero), and `write(buffer)` will start from position to limit which are both `0`, thus it writes nothing!

Answer (score 0):

wrap() delivers a buffer which is already flipped. Flipping it again basically empties it from the point of view of write() or get().